# Handling multiple device files having same major number but unique minor number

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am new to Linux Kernel Module Programming and have written a dummy character device driver to read and write to a dummy device (it is actually a sample program given in its documentation). The program runs fine when I try it with only one device file, the problem arises when I create a second dummy device file with same major number but different minor number (in sequence i.e, `1`). When I write to one file (say devfile0, `major : 250`, `minor : 0`) the data is also written to the other file (say devfile1, `major : 250`, `minor : 1`) but I just want to **write to devfile0** and **not to devfile1**. Is it possible? What am I possibly doing wrong?

Here is the kernel module I have created:

```
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/cdev.h>
#include<linux/fs.h>
#include<linux/semaphore.h>
#include<asm/uaccess.h>
#include<linux/kmod.h>

struct cdev *newDev;
int maj_no;
int ret;
dev_t crdev;
#define DEVICE_NAME "CryptoDevCHARDEVDRVR" 
struct dummy{
    char string[100];
    int length;
    struct semaphore sem;
    }device;

int device_open(struct inode *node,struct file *fp)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Atempting to open device file\n");
    if(down_interruptible(&device.sem) != 0)
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "%s : Unable to Lock file while open\n",DEVICE_NAME);
        return -1;
    }
    printk(KERN_ALERT "File open operation Complete\n");
    return 0;
}

ssize_t device_read(struct file* fp,char* buffer, size_t bufsize, loff_t* buffoff)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Reading from the device...\n");
    ret = copy_to_user(buffer,device.string,bufsize);
    device.length = bufsize;
    return ret;
}

ssize_t device_write(struct file* fp,const char* buffer, size_t bufsize, loff_t* buffoff)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Writing to the device...\n");
    ret = copy_from_user(device.string,buffer,bufsize);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "%s\n",device.string);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Written\n");
    device.length = bufsize;
    return ret;
}

int device_close(struct inode* node, struct file* fp)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Closing Device File");
    up(&device.sem);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Device Close Successfully");
    return 0;
}

struct file_operations fop = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = device_open,
    .release = device_close,
    .read = device_read,
    .write = device_write
};


static int hello_init(void)
{
    ret = alloc_chrdev_region(&crdev,0,50,DEVICE_NAME);
    if(ret < 0)
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "\n%s : Unable to assign Character Device Driver Region",DEVICE_NAME);
        return ret;
    }
    maj_no = MAJOR(crdev);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "%s : Major Number:%d\n",DEVICE_NAME,maj_no);
    newDev = cdev_alloc();
    newDev->ops = &fop;
    newDev->owner = THIS_MODULE;
    ret = cdev_add(newDev,crdev,50);
    if(ret < 0)
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "%s : Unable to Register Device Driver\n",DEVICE_NAME);
    }
    sema_init(&device.sem,1);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Successfully Initialised Device Driver\n");
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Test caller");
    return 0;
}

static void hello_destroy(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Killing Hello-Start.c ... Byeeee\n");
    cdev_del(newDev);
    unregister_chrdev_region(crdev,50);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "%s : Successfully Unregistered Driver\n",DEVICE_NAME);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Done");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_destroy);
```

Userspace application uses `open` syscall to open devfile0 and `write` syscall to write to devfile0.
Here is the code for that:

```
fp = open(DEVICE , O_RDWR);
if(fp == -1)
{
    printf("%s cann't be accessed right now try after sometime\n",DEVICE);
    exit(-1);
}

printf("Enter any Character String to transmit to Device:");
            fgets(buff,100,stdin);
            write(fp,buff,sizeof(buff));
            printf("\nWritten: %s\n",buff);
```

Comment: So, you need to create several underlying buffers, one per each device you allocate. [That question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36066635/3440745) describes how differenciate devices from file operations.

Answer (score -1):

> The major number tells you which driver is used to access the
>   hardware. Each driver is assigned a unique major number; all device
>   files with the same major number are controlled by the same driver.
>   All the above major numbers are 3, because they're all controlled by
>   the same driver.
>
> The minor number is used by the driver to distinguish between the
>   various hardware it controls. Returning to the example above, although
>   all three devices are handled by the same driver they have unique
>   minor numbers because the driver sees them as being different pieces
>   of hardware.

from [The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html),3.1.6.1. Major and Minor Numbers